# how to find xy position in javascript with offset

Tags: javascript, mozilla, cursor-position

hello i have some problem with my javascript code..

i want to get xy position the selected text in javascript, and i use offside function like this :

```
function findPosX(obj)
  {
    var curleft = 0;
    if(obj.offsetParent)
        while(1) 
        {
          curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
          if(!obj.offsetParent)
            break;
          obj = obj.offsetParent;
        }
    else if(obj.x)
        curleft += obj.x;
    return curleft;
  }

  function findPosY(obj)
  {
    var curtop = 0;
    if(obj.offsetParent)
        while(1)
        {
          curtop += obj.offsetTop;
          if(!obj.offsetParent)
            break;
          obj = obj.offsetParent;
        }
    else if(obj.y)
        curtop += obj.y;
    return curtop;
  }
```

but the result of position X,Y always 0 when i call this function to find position selected text

```
var select = window.getSelection();

var posX = findPosX(select);
var posY = findPosY(select);
```

and i use mozilla firefox..
please help me

Answer (score 2):

You will need to insert a dummy element at one end of the selection. Here's a function to get the coordinates of the start or end of the selection in all major browsers, including IE 6. Note that this requires support for the `getBoundingClientRect()` method of elements, which rules out Firefox 2. If you need to support that browser, you can use something like your `findPosX/Y` functions on the dummy element instead of `getBoundingClientRect()`.

```
function getSelectionCoordinates(start) {
    var x = 0, y = 0, range;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(sel.rangeCount - 1);
            range.collapse(start);
            var dummy = document.createElement("span");
            range.insertNode(dummy);
            var rect = dummy.getBoundingClientRect();
            x = rect.left;
            y = rect.top;
            dummy.parentNode.removeChild(dummy);
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.collapse(start);
        x = range.boundingLeft;
        y = range.boundingTop;
    }
    return {x: x, y: y};
}

var coords = getSelectionCoordinates(true);
alert(coords.x + ", " + coords.y);
```