# get range and coordinate of selected text

Tags: javascript, selectedtext

How to select the text of the page in FireFox?
For example, there's a paragraph of text, user select the text in those paragraph in a regular way.then, I want to know in which paragraph the text selected by user (in which position-xy coordinates, range position).

Answer (score 3):

You've asked about selection coordinates [twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122315/how-to-find-xy-position-in-javascript-with-offset) [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106109/selected-text-and-xy-coordinates). I know I've given you a [working answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122315/how-to-find-xy-position-in-javascript-with-offset), so why are you asking again?

Here's some code that will return you the innermost element containing the selection in Firefox (assuming a single selection; Firefox allows multiple selections). Hope it's helpful.

```
function getSelectionContainerElement() {
    var sel = window.getSelection(), el = null;
    if (sel.rangeCount) {
        var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        el = range.commonAncestorContainer;
        if (el.nodeType != 1) {
            el = el.parentNode;
        }
    }
    return el;
}
```

Comment: yes, but I am confused to implement
because the main problem is that I want to use the function to know the position of the selected text to locate an index of the array that I have.

Comment: Position of the selected text relative to what?

Comment: relative with the following text, for example i have sentence like this **the harvest is the process of gathering mature crops from the fields** and the selected text is 'gathering'. then i want to know indeces of the following text (i meant the text between 'gathering')

Answer (score 0):

refer the getSelection(), to get an object which contains information about the selected text and its position in the parent Element

Comment: can you give an example for me?

Answer (score 0):

[`Selection - MDC`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Selection) might help you to find answer of all your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the exact answer [here](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/PositionModule)

but this module is under construction, You can browse project and find this module.